# Link Server between 2 servers doesn't work but works on all other servers

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

A little background on what has been going on.  I have been in the process of upgrading our sql server from 2008 R2 to 2012.  The way I have been doing this is by taking the server to upgrade, lets call it Server A. Then taking a server a new server, lets call it Server C.

1. Moving all databases from Server A to Server C.
2. Renaming Server C to Server A and Server A to Server C.
3. Completely blowing away the Server C (old Server A).
4. Installing windows 2012, and SQL Server 2012 on Server.
5. Rename both servers to their original name.

The network team actually installed Windows server, got it on the network, etc.  I only installed SQL Server 2012.  I have done this with 8 servers and have had no problems from them so far.  Both servers are running SQL Server 11.0.3373 windows version 6.2 build(9200).  I also am sysadmin on all sql servers, but not a domain admin.

**The issue**

I am trying to create a link server from Server A to Server B.  I can create the link server without an error, but i get an error when i use it in a query.

**More relevant information**

The firewall is turned off on Server B on all these tests.

I am able to ping Server A from Server B and vice versa.

I did a tracert and it comes up with the correct server and ip address( from both servers)

**When I create the link server with **Other data source****

*“Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server” or “SQL Server native Client 11.0”*

I am able to query the master database when I query a user created database I get this error:

Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SERVER_B" does not contain the table ""UserDB"."dbo"."Table1"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

**SSMS**

When I RDP into the Server A, run SSMS, try to connect to Server B I get this error:

*"A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server (Provider TCP Provider, error:  0- The specified network name is no longer available.) (Microsoft SQL Server Error: 64)"*

**RDP**

When I try to RDP into Server B from Server A. I get an error that says "*This computer can't connect to the remote computer.* I also had a domain admin try and gets the same error.

**Server B to A errors**

I tried going the other way with it.

I RDP into Server B.  In SSMS I try to connect to Server A.  Below is the error i get.

*A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean for "server B" to be named "server C" in your description?
What step of the process are you having these troubles, have you already renamed the servers?
Why are you using "other" for the linked server, and not "sql server"
from the RDP issue, it doesn't seem to be a SQL Server issue.

Comment: I agree it doesn't seem to be a SQL issue as well.  Based on not being able to RDP into it from A to B.  Sorry its confusing. The first part i am just trying to give background on what has been going on in case it is relevant.  Server A & C were used during the upgrade.  Server A & B are where the issue lies.  Everything on Server A is working normally, except the link server between Server A & B. I do have SSRS running on Server A as well.  i can connect normally, but connecting is super slow.  i think that issue is related, but i didn't want to convolute things to much.

Comment: I tried doing a link server using "SQL Server" as well.  it creates it, but i get an error when i do any query using it.  i get this error  Msg 64, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available.